# Ошибка выборки записей из БД

Tags: hibernate, criteria, postgresql

Нужно вывести записи из таблицы в `ORАCLE`.Использую `CRITERIA` 
 :

```
 public List<MyOrder> myOrderListNew(Company company){
        Criteria criteria = session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(MyOrder.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("company.id", company.getId()));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("removeorder", false));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", "new"));
        criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("id"));
        List<MyOrder> myOrders = criteria.list();
        return myOrders;
    }
```

Каким должен быть критериа запрос на оракл.Этот же метод без проблем работает на `postgres`.
Куски из стэкстрейса :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1013)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)




java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)



Error : 1747, Position : 144, Sql = select this_.myOrder_id as myOrder_id1_6_0_, this_.myorder_company_id as myorder_company_id9_6_0_, this_.courier_id as courier_id10_6_0_, this_.date as date2_6_0_, this_.date_hms as date_hms3_6_0_, this_.hide as hide4_6_0_, this_.removeorder as removeorder5_6_0_, this_.selected as selected6_6_0_, this_.shops_id as shops_id11_6_0_, this_.status as status7_6_0_, this_.sum as sum8_6_0_ from myorder this_ where this_.myorder_company_id=:1  and this_.removeorder=:2  and this_.status=:3  order by this_.myOrder_id desc, OriginalSql = select this_.myOrder_id as myOrder_id1_6_0_, this_.myorder_company_id as myorder_company_id9_6_0_, this_.courier_id as courier_id10_6_0_, this_.date as date2_6_0_, this_.date_hms as date_hms3_6_0_, this_.hide as hide4_6_0_, this_.removeorder as removeorder5_6_0_, this_.selected as selected6_6_0_, this_.shops_id as shops_id11_6_0_, this_.status as status7_6_0_, this_.sum as sum8_6_0_ from myorder this_ where this_.myorder_company_id=? and this_.removeorder=? and this_.status=? order by this_.myOrder_id desc, Error Msg = ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612)
```

Проблема решена,оказалось `sum` и `date` ключевые слова `oracl`а.Добавил на поля аннотацию @Column(name="orderDate") и @Column(name="orderSum")

Comment: Вероятно у Вас проблемы с полем date - это служебное поле в Oracle и при создании таблицы, наверное, date было изменено на date_

Comment: @Orthodox да,спасибо.Оказалось date и sum ключевые слова.